# How do I join two tables in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, datamodel

I have two tables, table `A` with columns `x,y` and a table `B` with columns `y,z`.  Assume that data types are all `String` How do I join these two tables in Hibernate?
In SQL, the equivalent would be something like this:
`SELECT * from A a left outer join B b on a.y = b.y`

At the output I want the result table to have three columns: `x,y,z`. 
Could you please show how to do it through xml mapping (ie hbm.xlm) instead of .java AJOs.

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-tutorial-xml-mapping/ good example of OTO join by xml mapping

Comment: Thanks, #solar!  This is a great reference and an article.  I guess the million dollar question is:  When retrieving data from two separate sql tables through hibernate, is it better to do joins or do associations or just skip the whole hibernate hql and do sqlquery instead?